# Users Authentication in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

I was wondering, what's the best approach in creating users authentication for my asp.net-mvc web application.

Should I use the Forms authentication using a custom MembershipProvider ?
Or should I implement my own login and registration mechanism for my users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems silly to reinvent the wheel if you don't have a pressing business need to do so. I'd go with forms authentication with a custom provider (if necessary)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have some special needs, its always best to use the out-of-the-box solution. So perhaps you should describe what considerations makes you consider rolling your own? (And add that information to the original question - this will help people provide useful answers).

Comment: I just don't like the idea of infecting my DB with those asp.net tables and stored procedures. :-)

Comment: The problem is, I want to store extra data for the users and I don't want to use join on my queries - with the asp.net user table and the userdata table.

Comment: Every membership user has a GUID, just add that to the userdata table. no relationship needed.